# CISCO UCS servers and linux

Tags: linux, cisco, cisco-ucs

I've been given a CISCO ucs server to use (for a job a raspberry pie could do) with a LSI MegaRaid card in it (4 sas drives) and I'm having no luck at all getting Linux to boot off the RAID thing. It can find no boot sector on the raid devices, just loops through the nics looking for a pxi raid.

I can install happily (both Ubuntu and CentOS) but nothing will boot. The BIOS sees the virtual drive (tried raid 1 and raid 5 on the card).

The server has an SSD slot and an internal USB connector, both of which are enabled in the bios, but neither are seen by the installer (nor the bios by the looks of things). The internal USB connector seems to corrupt the data. I get no post and crazy stuff on the monitor when I plug anything in there. I have now managed to get it to boot by putting the usb drive in the rear usb connector, installing /boot on it and setting it as the boot device. Not ideal, but guess it will have to work.

Any one managed to get one of these machines to work with Linux?

Comment: I'm running an entire datacenter of UCS with RHEL on them - they work right out of the box for me. Two datacenters, actually, one with 6 chassis and the other with three, all fully populated. Roughly half are VMware ESXi blades. No special tweaks, no funky configuration settings - of the half that are linux, about half of those are booting from local disk, the other half from SAN disk.

Comment: While John technically answered your `Any one managed to get one of these pieces of rubbish to work with linux?` -- his answer, and your question, isn't really suitable for SF.  Can you edit your question with errors, screenshots, etc. that might allow John or others to help answer your real question of `After install of Linux on a Cisco UCS xxmodelxx it cannot boot and instead shows "xxyy"` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are Linux installation guides. You don't say if it B-Series or C-Series; my guess is C-Series: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/os-install-guides/linux/b_C-Series_Linux_Install.html

Hope this helps.

Bill Shields
Cisco

Comment: Summarize the content on the linked page.  Simply linking to the documentation does not make for a good answer as the page may fail to load in the future or may have different content.

Comment: Bad link, 404s.